# OpenCV libraries not found in Qt5 on OSX 10.10

Tags: macos, qt, opencv, clang

I am currently trying to use OpenCV in a Qt project. When I build it, i get the error:

```
error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

I know that there are many similar questions out there in the web, but none of the answers was actually able to fix my problem so far.

My specifications:

- Qt 5.4.0 (Clang 6.0 (Apple), 64 bit)
- Mac OSX 10.10.1
- OpenCV 2.4.9 installed from homebrew

My .pro file looks like this:

```
QT       += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = MainProject
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
LIBS += -lopencv_core
LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
LIBS += -lopencv_ml
LIBS += -lopencv_video
LIBS += -lopencv_features2d
LIBS += -lopencv_calib3d
LIBS += -lopencv_objdetect
LIBS += -lopencv_contrib
LIBS += -lopencv_legacy
LIBS += -lopencv_flann
```

I made sure the links actually link to the right locations. All the header files and all the .dylib files are there as well. I checked the type of the libraries:

```
$ file libopencv_core.dylib 
libopencv_core.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

In my project settings, the qmake command is:

```
qmake: qmake MainProject.pro -r -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64
```

Unfortunately I only have a basic understanding of these compile-things, so I am not too sure, whether it has something to do with clang? I read something about clang behaving somehow different on OSX 10.10 Yosemite, but I did not completely understand why. Info about my clang:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

I also tried to use the gcc-kit in Qt (GCC x86 64bit in /usr/bin), but this messed up a lot more, which I did not understand.

Does somebody have an idea what I am doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already including the directory `opencv2` in your `#include` statement. You should change your include path to just `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include`.

Comment: Okay seems this solved my problem. I am actually getting a LOT of other errors now, so I thought this cannot be right. But now that I looked into it it seems these error come from a different source and at least the linking to OpenCV works. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. If you can formulate your new errors into a new question, I am willing to help, our build environments are almost identical.

Comment: I broke the remaining errors down to a linking error with cv::VideoCapture. If you might want to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944074/cvvideocapture-from-string-gives-linker-error-in-qt5-on-mac